# How to populate a combo box in the userforms with names from a column in my worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I created:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim Total_rows_PU As Long
Total_rows_PU = Workbooks("Revised-Payroll (VBA Copy).xlsm").Worksheets("Payroll Update").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Me.cbxName.List = Worksheets("Payroll Update").Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_PU)

End Sub
```

This is the error I receive:

[image: Error Dialogue Box]

This is where the error occurs:
[image: Line of Error]

Working solution after considering the answer below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Total_rows_PU = Workbooks("Revised-Payroll (VBA Copy).xlsm").Worksheets("Payroll Update").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_PU)
    Me.cbxName.AddItem cell.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: In your line `Me.cbxName.List = Worksheets("Payroll Update").Range("A2:A & Total_rows_PU")` you've misplaced your closing quote. It should be `Me.cbxName.List = Worksheets("Payroll Update").Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_PU)`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I revised the main post and came up with a new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the right way of populating combobox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A9")
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next

End Sub
```

It populates combobox with values from cells in range `A1:A9` (you have to specifiy your own). Here's how it works:

[image]

Values indicate cell address :)

Of course, @TotsieMae pointed lot's of good resources - I recommend them :)

Comment: Thank you this works well even dynamically. :). They are good references, but more complicated than it should be and does not really have what I need right now. Updated the main post for the fixed code.